# event characters

Tags: objective-c, events

What event character is the return key? for example:

If I used "[event characters]" and pressed "a" and then enter, what would come up? When I check it's just "a" and a space. but how would I simulate a return press in a string value?

Thanks,
Elijah

Comment: What do you mean by simulating? Do you want to make an `NSEvent` and then feed it to the system?

Comment: yes, how do I do that? sorry for being vague :D